# angular 2 does not trigger callback function after successful google login

Tags: angular

```
import {Component,Directive,OnInit,NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
declare const gapi:any;
declare const $:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'mysite',
  templateUrl:'./app/template.html'
})
export class Test{ 
    userAuthToken;
    userDisplayName;
    constructor(private zone: NgZone){   
        gapi.load('auth2',this.initnow);

        this.zone.run(() => {
                 console.log(this);
                $.proxy(this.onGoogleLoginSuccess, this);
        });
    }

    initnow(){
        gapi.auth2.init({client_id:'9511021809-qqke9m46imnmrged8u7u66ilj168bi9t.apps.googleusercontent.com'});
    }

     ngAfterViewInit() {
        gapi.signin2.render(
          this.googleLoginButtonId,{
            "onSuccess": this.onGoogleLoginSuccess,
            "scope": "profile",
            "theme": "dark"
        });
    }

    public onGoogleLoginSuccess(loggedInUser) {
        this.userAuthToken = loggedInUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        this.userDisplayName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        console.log("onGoogleLoginSuccess called: ",this.userAuthToken,this.userDisplayName);
  }
}
```

template.html

```
<div id="{{googleLoginButtonId}}"></div>
```

**onGoogleLoginSuccess** function is not getting called. 
Can anyone suggest, what is missing in this code?

I am trying to integrate google login with my website.
but nothing getting called after google login page disappear.
thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set an id in `googleLoginButtonId`. Just set it up and the button should work.

```
export class Test{ 
    userAuthToken;
    userDisplayName;
    googleLoginButtonId = 'google_login_button_id';
    ...
}
```

But, if that was your issue, the button shouldn't appear at all!! So, if you did set `googleLoginButtonId` but forgot to add it in your question. The problem could be in this line

```
$.proxy(this.onGoogleLoginSuccess, this);
```

I am not a `jQuery` guy, but I looked up [`proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and it says in the description:

> **Description:** Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context.

So, you need to save the new returned function and pass it to the `onSuccess` callback:

```
proxyedSignInSuccess;
constructor(private zone: NgZone){
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.proxyedSignInSuccess = $.proxy(this.onGoogleLoginSuccess, this);
    });
}
...

ngAfterViewInit() {
    gapi.signin2.render(
      this.googleLoginButtonId,{
        "onSuccess": this.proxyedSignInSuccess,
        "scope": "profile",
        "theme": "dark"
    });
}
```

Or, just to make sure. Maybe try instead:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    gapi.signin2.render(
      this.googleLoginButtonId,{
        "onSuccess": (user) => this.zone.run(() => this.onGoogleLoginSuccess(user)),
        "scope": "profile",
        "theme": "dark"
    });
}
```